# Adding Color to new style ipython (v5) prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

Update to the newly release ipython5 today. Started up the interactive prompt and received:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:440: UserWarning: As of IPython 5.0 `PromptManager` config will have no effect and has been replaced by TerminalInteractiveShell.prompts_class
warn('As of IPython 5.0 `PromptManager` config will have no effect'
```

Yanked out my old config settings to customize and colorize the prompt and went looking for the new way to customize the prompt and found it, very cool. Used the new class style from the [example code](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config/details.html#custom-prompts):

```
class MyPrompt(Prompts):
    def in_prompt_tokens(self, cli=None):
        return [(Token, os.getcwd()),
                (Token.Prompt, ' >>>')]
```

Put this into a startup script and it works great, except it by default doesn't colorize the Token line, the Token.Prompt is made light green.

Attempted to use the old config method colors, (r'{color.Green}') but that doesn't work here. Any pointers in the correct direction would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: I like the multiline editing of this new Ipython.  It may take some time to get used to the different tab completion behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from IPython.terminal.prompts import Prompts, Token
import os

class MyPrompt(Prompts):

    def in_prompt_tokens(self, cli=None):   # default
        return [
            (Token.Prompt, 'In ['),
            (Token.PromptNum, str(self.shell.execution_count)),
            (Token.Prompt, ']: '),
        ]

    def in_prompt_tokens(self, cli=None):  # sample
        return [(Token, os.getcwd()),
                 (Token.Prompt, ' >>>')]

    def in_prompt_tokens(self, cli=None):   # custom
        path = os.path.basename(os.getcwd())
        return [
            (Token.Prompt, '<'),
            (Token.PromptNum, '~/'+path),
            (Token.Prompt, '>'),
            (Token.Prompt, '['),
            (Token.PromptNum, str(self.shell.execution_count)),
            (Token.Prompt, ']: '),
        ]

    def in_prompt_tokens(self, cli=None):   # custom
        path = os.path.basename(os.getcwd())
        return [
            (Token.PromptNum, str(self.shell.execution_count)),
            (Token.Prompt, ':'),
            (Token.PromptNum, '~/'+path),
            (Token.Prompt, '$ '),
        ]

"""
use:
import myprompt as MP
ip=get_ipython()
ip.prompts=MP.MyPrompt(ip)
"""
```

I experimented with various prompts with this script. It includes the default  `in_prompt_tokens` method, the example customization and a couple of alternatives.  The last imitates my `bash` prompt

```
73:~/mypy$
```

In looks like the tuple `(Token..., str)` sets the color of the string according to the `token_type`.  `Token`, `Token.Prompt`, `Token.PromptNum` are possible types.  Look at `Token.<tab>` for more  (such as `OutPrompt(Num)`).

```
IPython/terminal/prompts.py
```

I probably won't use any of these because I like the default matching `In /Out` pairs.  Besides I can use `--term-title` to show the directory in the tab title.

Comment: My VIM autocomplete didn't do anything for Token. so I moved on. Tried from the ipython terminal itself and from that it works. This helped, thanks a bunch.

Comment: Add the line `c.InteractiveShell.prompts_class = MyPrompt ` to `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` after the above (because `get_ipython()` there returns `None`). Thanks to https://newton.cx/~peter/2015/11/extensible-prompts-in-jupyter-console/

Answer (score 4):

Simple example showing how to color the prompt in red:

```
from IPython.terminal.prompts import Token

ipy_config = get_config()

ipy_config.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style_overrides = {
    Token.Prompt: '#ff0000',
}
```

More advanced example that changes prompt color according to environment variable (useful if you play alot with staging/live systems):

```
# Example showing how to change color of prompt and prompt string in specific environments.
# put into ~/.ipython/profile_${YOURPROFILE}/ipython_config.py and start ipython with:
# PROFILE_LIVE ipython --profile ${YOURPROFILE}
import os

from IPython.terminal.prompts import Prompts, Token

ipy_config = get_config()


class MyPrompt(Prompts):
    environment = None

    def in_prompt_tokens(self, cli=None):
        return [
            (Token.Prompt, '{} ['.format(MyPrompt.environment)),
            (Token.PromptNum, str(self.shell.execution_count)),
            (Token.Prompt, ']: ')
        ]


if 'PROFILE_LIVE' in os.environ:
    ipy_config.TerminalInteractiveShell.highlighting_style_overrides = {
        Token.Prompt: '#ff0000',
    }
    MyPrompt.environment = 'LIVE'
    ipy_config.TerminalInteractiveShell.prompts_class = MyPrompt
```