# What the equivalent of the --nosep option in ipython5?

Tags: ipython

I want to continue working without an extra empty line between the last output and the input prompt, as I did with earlier ipythons using the **--nosep** option.

I now use IPython version 5.1.0. It helpfully informs me that:

[TerminalIPythonApp] WARNING | Config option `nosep` not recognized by `TerminalIPythonApp`.
    /usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:448: UserWarning: As of IPython 5.0 `PromptManager` config will have no effect and has been replaced by TerminalInteractiveShell.prompts_class

And [the documentation](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/details.html) explains how to define a prompts_class. But how do I get the functionality equivalent to the --nosep option? I can overwrite the in and out prompts (a-la [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275585/adding-color-to-new-style-ipython-v5-prompt), with the in_prompt_tokens and out_prompt_tokens methods), but the extra empty line remains.

Comment: At some point, perhaps when I switched OS, ipython 5.1.0 started respecting the ol' --nosep option.